# How to i sort a List<Map<String,Object>> in java

Tags: java

I am getting

```
  List<Map<String,Object>> listMap = [
    {employee=17, fromdate=2010-08-01 00:00:00.0, full_inc=25572.0000},
    {employee=17, fromdate=2010-09-01 00:00:00.0, full_inc=28347.0000},  
    {employee=17, fromdate=2010-10-01 00:00:00.0, full_inc=37471.0000},
    {employee=17, fromdate=2011-02-01 00:00:00.0, full_inc=47033.0000},
    {employee=17, fromdate=2011-07-01 00:00:00.0, full_inc=50592.0000}
  ]
```

can anyone help me how do i sort this list of map based on full_inc from high amount to low amount in java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a custom comparator, but you need your values (currently `Object`) to implement `Comparable`. Based on the current declaration of your list, you can't do it (how do you compare two random objects?):

```
List<Map<String,Comparable>> listMap = ...
Collections.sort(listMap, new Comparator<Map<String, Comparable>> () {

    @Override
    public int compare(Map<String, Comparable> m1, Map<String, Comparable> m2) {
        return m2.get("full_inc").compareTo(m1.get("full_inc")); //descending
    }
});
```

Note: you need to add error checking.

Answer (score 5):

You can use in Java 8 which is given below :

```
listMap.sort(Comparator.comparing(m->(double) m.get("full_inc"),Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.reverseOrder())));
```

Answer (score 1):

I would

- Make your maps object of a custom class.
- Make your custom class implement Comparable
- Use Collections.sort()

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1 is to put all entries you want to sort in a `TreeMap<K,V>`([TreeMap doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)) where K is you criteria on which you sort (here full_inc) and V is what you want to sort. Then TreeMap.entrySet will be iterated following the compare() order of your `K`.

Solution 2 is to create your own [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) class using full_inc to compare with objects of the same class and use [Collections.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) with it.

Solution 3 is almost the same as 2, using [Collections.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) with a comparator comparing two instance of your custom class based on their `getFullInc()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Collections.sort() with your own comparator.